# Map xml element to Excel cell using Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing, apache-poi, fileinputstream

Hi I have a business requirement in which when an xml element is changed, the same value shall be updated in an excel automatically,I am thinking if there is a way to map the xml element to the excel cell programmatically using Java I hope that I can achieve this, can any one suggest me what API's or documentation is available that I can refer in order for me to achieve this?

Comment: The process will be: Observing changing of the XML; On change the XML element, get the changed value, open the Excel workbook file, get the needed worksheet, get the needed cell, set the value into that cell, write the workbook file and close it. The observing part depends on what kind of XML that is and how you are processing this currently. The Excel workbook part is achievable using [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#ReadWriteWorkbook).

Comment: is there a way that I recognize changes in xml programatically? if a value in xml is changed somehow an action shall be triggered and execute the code to write in excel is it possible?

Comment: As asked already, what kind of XML is it and how you are processing the changing on this currently? In other words who changes the XML and how?

Comment: a 2d drawing data is our xml, curretly we are doing this manually now we trying to automate this task.

Comment: OK, as I had feared. This question is too broad to be answered here since you are not able precisely describing your requirements but only making vague allusions.

Comment: let me explain it clearly, 2d drawing can be converted into a neutral format with a defined schema and its called an ISO 15926 xml.on the other hand way we maintain certain excels that explains the data about all equipments and other components. the challenge we now face is the data disconnect between the 2d drawings and the datasheets(excels), now we are doing this manually but going forward we want to do it automatically. the solution that I got in hand is create a cron job that runs every day and writes data from ISO 15926 into the datasheets, I am looking for other efficient ways. if any?